# Backup all privileges related to specific user of MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysqldump

I want to backup all privileges related to specific user (for example `u_1`) from a MySQL database and restore that in another server. As described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100516/119976), `The 'mysql' database contains users/privileges/passwords.` So I have to backup all related data from all tables of `mysql` database (`mysql.user`,`mysql.db`, ...). I can run this command:

```
$ mysqldump -u root --flush-privileges -r mysql.sql -p mysql
```

But of course the `mysql.sql` contains *all users and all privileges*.

Also I tried this command:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -p --where="user.user='u_1'" mysql user> mysql.sql
```

But as expected, it only contains a row of `mysql.user` table.

Is there a way to strip out other users except of `u_1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the output from

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'u_1'@localhost;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'u_1'@'%';
```

(and any other 'hosts' involved.)

Then replay `GRANTs` to establish hist credentials elsewhere.

Comment: Do I have to restore them manually?

Comment: If you capture the output, you could send that to `mysql -u root <grants.sql` -- that's not quite "manually".

Answer (score 2):

By this script you can backup all of mysql's users except `root`:

```
mysql -BNe "select concat('\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user where user != 'root'" | \
while read uh; do mysql -BNe "show grants for $uh" | sed 's/$/;/; s/\\\\/\\/g'; done > grants.sql
```

So, if you just need to export a specific user like (`u_1`)

```
mysql -BNe "select concat('\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user where user = 'u_1'" | \
while read uh; do mysql -BNe "show grants for $uh" | sed 's/$/;/; s/\\\\/\\/g'; done > grants.sql
```

And you can restore it by:

```
mysql -u root <grants.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for appending the semicolon.`SHOW GRANTS` does not include it. I do the same thing : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127